# Hello guys, I'm not experienced with programming and I would like to run the Mergesort algorithm in Python for a default generated list

Tags: python, numpy, mergesort

It takes the random list I generated but the output is something a lot different than I expected.
I think that something goes wrong with merging.
e.g. : Input --> [267,168,236,190,2,500,4,45,86]
Output --> [2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,45,45,86]
Thank you in advance.

```
import numpy as np

def mergeSort(myList):
    if len(myList) > 1:
        mid = len(myList) // 2
        left = myList[:mid]
        right = myList[mid:]

        # Recursive call on each half
        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)

        # Two iterators for traversing the two halves
        i = 0
        j = 0
    
        # Iterator for the main list
        k = 0
        
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] <= right[j]:
            # The value from the left half has been used
                myList[k] = left[i]
              # Move the iterator forward
                i += 1
            else:
                myList[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
            # Move to the next slot
            k += 1

        # For all the remaining values
        while i < len(left):
            myList[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(right):
            myList[k]=right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

list1 = np.random.randint(low=1, high=800, size=100)
myList = list1

print("Given array is", end="\n")
print(myList)

mergeSort(myList)

print("Sorted array is: ", end="\n")
print(myList)
```

Comment: I have written the answer, you could accept as answer if it answers the problem

Comment: You have an argument/variable called `myList`, but you generate a `numpy` array with `np.random`.  For iterative things like this actually using a `list` may be better.  And for certain kinds of in-place or replacement actions, lists and arrays behave differently.  Don't casually substitute one for the other.  At the very least keep the names straight, for our sake if not yours.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is only with inplace manipulation of your original list. merge sort needs extra space O(n).

you could simply rewrite your code like this to work: (notice that it is your code, only I modified two lines, look for # changed ...)

```
import numpy as np

def mergeSort(myList):
    if len(myList) > 1:
        mid = len(myList) // 2
        left = myList[:mid].copy() # changed this line
        right = myList[mid:].copy() # changed this line

        # Recursive call on each half
        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)

        # Two iterators for traversing the two halves
        i = 0
        j = 0
    
        # Iterator for the main list
        k = 0
        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] <= right[j]:
            # The value from the left half has been used
                myList[k] = left[i]
              # Move the iterator forward
                i += 1
            else:
                myList[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
            # Move to the next slot
            k += 1

        # For all the remaining values
        while i < len(left):
            myList[k] = left[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1

        while j < len(right):
            myList[k]=right[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1


myList = np.random.randint(low=1, high=800, size=100)

print("Given array is", end="\n")
print(myList)

mergeSort(myList)

print("Sorted array is: ", end="\n")
print(myList)
```

However this is not very optimized version of implementation for the mergsort specially in python.

Here is better implementation, pure python (from: https://github.com/amirhm/algo-data-scratch/blob/main/Sorting/mergesort.ipynb)

```
def mergesort(l):
    def merge(l, r):
        lp, rp = 0 , 0
        d = []
        while lp < len(l) and rp < len(r):
            if l[lp] < r[rp]:
                d.append(l[lp])
                lp += 1
            else:
                d.append(r[rp])
                rp += 1
        if rp < len(r): d.extend(l[lp:])
        if lp < len(l): d.extend(r[rp:])
        return d
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return l
    n = len(l)
    return merge(mergesort(l[:n//2]), mergesort(l[n//2:]))
```

or much more abstract only in 9 lines:

```
def mergesort(l):
    def merge(l, r):
        res = []
        while l and r : ((res.append(l.pop())) if (l[-1] > r[-1])  else res.append(r.pop()))
        #while r or l: res.append(r.pop()) if r else (res.append(l.pop()))
        if r: res[::-1].extend(r)
        if l: res[::-1].extend(l)
        return res
    if len(l) <= 1: return l
    return merge(mergesort(l[:len(l) // 2]), mergesort(l[len(l) // 2:]))
```